# PyQt5 Change UI while another UI is already running

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I am new to the python world :P

I want to create a UI using PyQt5 that will create another window with a click of a button.

Now the thing is that everything will pass through the Controller and will be executed by an Action. This action will have the code to create the starting UI and the next one as well.

Please check the code below:

CREATING THE UI

```
def init_view(self,action,viewToCreate,cls): 
        if action=="start":
            self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
            self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()

            #cls IS THE CLASS FOR THE UI
            #setupUI IS THE METHOD THAT CREATES THE UI
            self.ui = cls.Ui_Class(controllerReceived)
            self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
            self.window.show()
            sys.exit(self.app.exec_())

        #HERE IS THE PROBLEM, IT SHOULD CREATE A SECOND UI
        #WHILE CLOSING THE FIRST ONE   
        elif action=="change":

            #I CAN CREATE A UI USING THE FOLLOWING CODE
            #BUT ONLY IF IS CONTAINED IN THE STARTING UI
            self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            ui = cls.Ui_Class()
            ui.setupUi(self.window)
            self.window.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is two separate windows, why not save each to a separate variable, then show and hide as necessary, e.g.

```
self.window1 = MyWindow1()
self.window2 = MyWindow2()
...
if action == 'start':
    self.window1.show()
    self.window2.hide()
elif action == 'change':
    self.window1.hide()
    self.window2.show()
```